# How can I read some variable in one inputline? (Java)

Tags: java, io

How can I read some variable in one inputline in Java?

*Sorry for my beginner english*

Forexample: 
`Enter a, b, c: 1.0 3 1 <Enter>`
Then I would like to the a=1.0, b=3 and c=1.

How can I implement in Java (and C#)?

I tried in this format, but It doesn't work when the input number is an real number

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(" ");
    double a = sc.nextDouble();
    double b = sc.nextDouble();
    double c = sc.nextDouble();
    sc.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will read numbers seperated by space or newlines. Just a newline or hitting enter will terminate scanning.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Pattern newlineOrSpace = Pattern.compile(System
        .getProperty("line.separator") + "|\\s");
sc.useDelimiter(newLineOrSpace);
List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
System.out.println("Enter numbers:");
while (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
    numbers.add(sc.nextDouble());
}
for (Double number : numbers) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Sample Run

```
Enter numbers:
1 2 3
5.5 7.2
.1

1.0
2.0
3.0
5.5
7.2
0.1
```

**EDIT**

You could input the numbers into seperate variables:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Pattern newlineOrSpace = Pattern.compile(System
        .getProperty("line.separator") + "|\\s");
sc.useDelimiter(newlineOrSpace);
System.out.print("Enter a, b, c: ");
double a = sc.nextDouble();
double b = sc.nextDouble();
double c = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.format("a = %f, b = %f, c = %f", a, b, c);
```

Sample Run

```
Enter a, b, c: 1.0 5 9
a = 1.000000, b = 5.000000, c = 9.000000
```

Comment: It is not bad :). But when I want to use this format:
`  `Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
  Pattern newlineOrSpace = Pattern.compile(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "|\\s");
  sc.useDelimiter(newlineOrSpace);
  double a=sc.nextDouble();
  double b=sc.nextDouble();
  double c=sc.nextDouble();`
It don't work... throw exception. 
I would like use this format because after this I have to calculate a quadratic equation.

Comment: I've added an example with the input saved into discrete variables. It should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

i think your solution is pretty good. better take ";" as a delimiter instead of " ", that will make it more clear. if I want to type a number like 3.5, i have to use "," instead of ".". and i think you have to use the delimiter after your last number again.

this is my test with your code:
input: 
    1,3;4;5;
output:
    --> 1.3
    --> 4.0
    --> 5.0

Comment: Yes I know that, but the inputs is generated by the computer in this format (numbers between space). It is an university homework...